# Create PdfTextFormField in iText7 exclusively for numeric input

Tags: java, c#, itext7

I need a **PdfTextFormField** that can carry only numeric input as decimal values (currency). Other characters must be forbidden. Any hints can also be given in Java although I code in C#.

Comment: In which pdf viewer shall that work?

Comment: Above all in Adobe Reader. But (if possible) also in other readers.

Comment: Ok. I asked because André's answer requires a viewer with javascript support and the Adobe object model. Most Adobe Reader installations fulfill this ("most" because you can deactivate javascript support in Adobe Reader; usually it is active, though), most other viewers don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Actually Adobe has some functions that you can use for validation (watch ***AFNumber_*** stuff on the code below):

```
public void helloWorldForm() throws IOException {
    logger.info("create PDF on {}", DEST);

    final PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(DEST);
    final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

    try (final Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)) {

        document.add(new Paragraph("Number with 2 decimal places"));

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
        PdfTextFormField nameField = PdfTextFormField.createText(pdfDocument,
                new Rectangle(99, 753, 425, 15), "value", "");
        form.addField(nameField);

        PdfAction validation = PdfAction.createJavaScript("AFNumber_Format(2,0,0,0,\"\", true);");
        nameField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.F, validation);

        validation = PdfAction.createJavaScript("AFNumber_Keystroke(2,0,0,0,\"\", true);");
        nameField.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.K, validation);

    }

    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

This will create a form that will only take numbers, and you can use a "." (period) for decimal places.

The PDF Reference mentions these Dictionary keys:

- PdfName.F - "A JavaScript action to be performed before the field is formatted to display its current value. This action can modify the field’s value before formatting."
- PdfName.K - "A JavaScript action to be performed when the user types a keystroke into a text field or combo box or modifies the selection in a scrollable list box. This action can check the keystroke for validity and reject or modify it."

You can find some documentation on these *functions* on [Adobe's Forms API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/FormsAPIReference.pdf) (page 119).

This mimics what you can set within Adobe Acrobat PRO:

[image: screenshot of Adobe Acrobat PRO]

(I have tested this method in Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader. It is possible that some reader may not support it, in which case, I would recommend you implement your own Javascript validation in a similar fashion)